# Making a nested link system change it's <li> bg on hover of other <li>

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hoping someone has the time to help me out with some jquery confusion?

I am trying to get the parent of an elements background change when the child is hovered and then go back to its default when the childs hover has ended.

The problem I have at the moment is with my script I cannot get the code to return the background colour to its default from the *.css file, when the hove ris lost the parents background remains the colour it was changed too.

The Jquery::

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.sf-menu li li li').hover(function() {
         var currentID = "#";
         currentID += $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');

         $('ul.sf-menu li li ul').parent(currentID).css('background', 'pink');
         $('ul.sf-menu li li li').focusout().css('background', '#00467F');
    });
});
```

The HTML::

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
    <li id='education'><a>Education</a>
        <ul>
            <li class='education' id='6'><a href='#' title='Desktops'>Desktops</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class='education2'><a href='#' title='#'>#</a></li>
                    <li class='education2'><a href='#' title='#'>#</a></li>
                    <li class='education2'><a href='#' title='#'>#</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class='education' id='9'><a href='#' title='#'>#</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class='education2'><a href='#' title='#'>#</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class='education' id='11'><a href='#' title='#'>#</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class='education2'><a href='#' title='#'>#</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class='education' id='14'><a href='#' title='#'>#</a>
                <ul>
                     <li class='education2'><a href='#' title='#'>#</a></li>
                     <li class='education2'><a href='#' title='#'>#</a></li>
                     <li class='education2'><a href='#' title='#'>#</a></li>
                     <li class='education2'><a href='#' title='#'>#</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you in advance anyone that can shine a light on this problem for me.

Comment: The first thing I'm seeing wrong is that your hover method is not taking advantage of the binding of handlers for mouseenter and mouseleave. You don't need to do all that "focus" stuff. See an nominal example here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Gw5dR/

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery syntax suggested here, as it has an In and an Out handler:

http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1

```
.hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you should utilize the [power of hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), as provided by jQuery. Additionally, you also do not need to make your selectors quite as complicated. Again, utilizing the power of jQuery to move around in the DOM, you can [select the parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) of the li with almost no effort (there's even a nice example in the documentation). Here is an [example here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Gw5dR/1/) that (I believe) is what you want to do. If not, please let me know, and I will fix it/update it.

Just so you understand the code:

```
$(function() {
    $('li').hover(function() {
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'pink');
    }, function() {
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'white');
    });
});
```

Based on the list item that is being hovered over, there are two functions defined. The first is for mouseenter and the second is for mouseleave. Basically, you just need to tell the DOM how to update based on either of those functions. After that, any time you hover over an li, its parent will be highlighted with the color that you wish.

Comment: Hi Jas, I have tried your example this morning and it worked but only on the first level of the nested links, what im hoping to achieve is to get the 2nd level of links to change its background colour once the 3rd level is hovered over. I used my old selector path from my example which worked to identify the correct level but that doesnt work in your code.

Comment: @Daniel - Give this a shot: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Gw5dR/3/ - I'm having a bit of trouble with the right selector (the lists don't appear to work the way I think they should). If this isn't what you're looking for, maybe someone else can chime in on the example.

Answer (score 0):

- Use jQuery's `hover` with two parameters, first will be called `monmousemove`, the second will be called `onmouseout`. Use the first to set your css, use the second to clear/reset css.
- To reset css back to it's stylesheet values, set to `''`.

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/SF3Tz/

Comment: Hi Aularon, Just tried using your example code and it works really well :) only extra addition I need to make is to define the bg colour for each of the first level links. I.E. in the example I first posted, the set of links there are for the education category and thus have an individual set of colours for bgs and hovers, I also have 2 other categories and I need the code to know that it is inside a specific category aka (Education) and then change the bgs accordingly. Hope you can help.